# Selenium webdriver: TypeError: isDisplayed is not a function

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to see if an element is hidden or visible. My code looks like this:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
  .build();

return driver.isDisplayed("#some-id")
```

I've seen other posts about using a selector instead of a locator, but I believe that's what I'm doing here - the webdriver docs don't differentiate between usage for `isDisplayed` and `isExisting`, and I call `isExisting` in the same way with no errors.

Comment: The error is correct. isDisplayed is not a method directly tied to the driver. The method is used to check if element is displayed or not on the browser.

Comment: yep, it's a method of a WebElement: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html